# Flickering horizontal white stripes on the lower half of the monitor

Tags: display, hdmi

English isn't my first language and I don't have friends so I am not very good at communication. I have recorded a video using my phone's camera to complement my description. Because it uses my phone's camera video quality is poor.

[Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13HpUdygdeR8HQIWblGIPeFDDlbnyyYuB/view?usp=sharing)

I use a desktop computer which is custom-built, meaning the keyboard, mouse, monitor, HDD, SSD, RAM, CPU, and motherboard are of different brands and bought separately.

I have a dedicated graphics card, I installed the GPU to the motherboard myself and I did my best to ensure the GPU is secured to the motherboard but I don't know if the contact remains proper.

The monitor is connected to the GPU via an HDMI cable, the HDMI cable was a cheap one and I don't know its quality.

The problem is simple, at irregular intervals, typically several hours apart, the lower half of the screen on the monitor will be filled with horizontal stripes that are very thin and rapidly changing, they flicker for several seconds and then disappear. After a few minutes (3-5) they appear again, but with less intensity(?), this repeats for about 5 times before stopping. Only to reappear hours later.

I haven't narrowed this down to a cause, but I have found a way to reproduce the problem with high probability of success, but the method isn't very easy to use. If I left the monitor powered off for several hours, and then power on the monitor, the screen will show the brand of the monitor, which consists of giant red text on a blue background.

On first powering on after hours of being powered off, on the title screen it is almost guaranteed for the stripes to show up, in this case these stripes will be completely white.

Then the screen will fade to black and show whatever is from the computer, now the stripes aren't white but very thin artifacts of what is supposed to be on screen, they are what should be originally on the screen, compressed vertically while maintaining horizontal sizes, so that they form very thin bands, and these bands overlap each other.

I have just managed to reproduce the issue by powering on the monitor for the first time today, and then I recorded using my phone while it recurs. I didn't record this occurrence using screen recording on my computer, then I tried to record another occurrence using screen recording software on my computer, it isn't as intense(?), playback of the video reveals that the stripes don't show up in the signals, so that it is safe to eliminate the GPU as the cause.

I then disconnected the HDMI cable from the monitor and powered on the monitor again, the title screen showed up and there were the white stripes, then it says "no signal" and shuts down. This seem to suggest that the problem is caused by the monitor, but the problem didn't recur on subsequent tests, which is odd because the tests were performed well within the usual time window of recurrence.

Also sometimes the monitor will turn completely black, this happens at random intervals usually several hours apart, adjusting the HDMI cable is sufficient to make it work again, suggesting faulty contact, but sometimes after a few seconds it automatically begins to work properly again.

During all of these incidents the monitor is always properly connected to a working power source. The monitor is an IPS LCD monitor.

What could have caused this issue?

Comment: At first look, this sounds like the buildup of static electricity. You could check by connecting it to some power-sync with a metallic wire, or just try touching the monitor on some conducting surface after a long sleep, to discharge it.

Answer (score 0):

Your video seems to show the flicker occuring on the display's boot screen. If this is the case, the issue is when the panel, display engine, or an internal connection between them within the monitor itself. Since these aren't user serviceable you'll need to change the entire display.

You can confirm this by turning on the monitor's OSD (if it is positioned in the affected area) when you also see the issue. If the OSD is affected, then the issue is within the display itself.